# Best facebook graph api wrapper for python to be used on google app engine(GAE)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, facebook-graph-api

Is there any facebook graph api wrapper for python/Django to be used on GAE? What are the best  practices?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690723/facebook-graph-api-and-django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [PythonForFacebook](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk). It works pretty well.